# ASP.NET Web API Documentation duplicate entries

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, swagger

I'm trying to create documentation for my API's. So far I've tried with [Swagger.Net](https://github.com/miketrionfo/Swagger.Net) and [Web API help pages](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/creating-web-apis/creating-api-help-pages)

Both tools provided me with correct documentation which is generated from XML but both of them showed me duplicate entries. I'm supposing that's related how my routes are configured:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
   name: "Sample1",
   routeTemplate: "sample1/{controller}/{id}",
   defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
   name: "Sample2",
   routeTemplate: "sample2/{controller}/{id}",
   defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });
```

What I see in view is methods both from Sample1 and Sample2, something like this:

```
../sample1/method1
../sample1/method2

../sample2/method1
../sample2/method2
```

And I want this:

```
../sample1/method1

../sample2/method2
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I am a bit confused by your post. Can you give more details as to why do you have 2 routes here which look similar? like what is your scenario? also when you say `/sample1/method1`, is `sample1` a controller or is `method1` a controller...in any case, the way HelpPage works is that it iterates through each route in the route collection and gets all the controllers and actions which can be reached from that route....

Comment: oh sorry, didn't explained very well. `sample1` and `sample2` are sub-folders under Controllers, so therefore I've configured two routes. I'm guessing because of that, HelpPage iterates twice through all api controllers. So question would be how to distinct controllers inside those sub folder and not to display duplicate methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your last comment, you could do this by setting route constraints and expect HelpPage to show up correctly. Example below:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "AdminRoute",
            routeTemplate: "api/folder1/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional },
            constraints: new { controller = "Roles|Users" }
        );

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "RegularRoute",
            routeTemplate: "api/folder2/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional },
            constraints: new { controller = "Products|Reviews" }
        );
```

NOTE: if you try to make folder to be route variable, then HelpPage will not be able to show up the help documentation.